# Is There a Quantum Conjugate Variable to Rest Mass, in Some Cases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Consider a non-relativistic quantum LC circuit (type of quantum harmonic oscillator). Charge and flux are canonically conjugate variables. Although the charge of an electron is constant, the amount of charge (number of electrons) in the capacitor can be described by a wave function, as can the flux from the inductor.

Therefore, although the rest mass of an electron is also constant, can't the total rest mass of the electrons in the capacitor (in the non-relativistic quantum LC circuit) also be characterized by a wave function (and mass operator $\hat{M}$). If so, then what is the conjugate variable to the total rest mass of the electrons? I think that $\hat{M}$ and $\hat{Q}$ (charge operator) commute, so, maybe the flux is also the conjugate variable to the mass? (BTW, I realize that if I say non-relativistic, I need only say "mass", and not "rest mass", but just being "belt and suspenders" about what I mean.)

Comment: ...what would that mass operator be if not just the identity multiplied by the mass? It's straightforward that there are no conjugate operators to the identity operator since it commutes with everything.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Sounds like my assumption that any quantum variable must have  a conjugate variable is false. But, another thought is if one knew the total charge on the capacitor, then divide the single electron charge (constant) into that to get the total number of electrons and then multiply that result by the single electron mass (also constant), in order to obtain the total electron mass on the capacitor. Then, since charge and flux are conjugates, mass and flux would be conjugate for the quantum LC circuit. More generally, mass and generalized momentum would be conjugates.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Continuing from my previous comment, maybe $\hat{M}$ in generalized momentum space is not $M\hat{I}$? In my previous comment, I think flux can be considered as a generalized momentum, analogous to momentum in the mass-spring type of harmonic oscillator.